# Simulated MLE does not exist, when trying to Bootstrap likelihood combinant

Tags: maximum-likelihood, bootstrap, likelihood

Consider this simple logistic model:

We have ten $0/1$ observations $y_1,...,y_{10}.$ We model with an intercept and a predictor variable.The ten first observations have predictor value  $X_i=0$, and remaining ten next receive $X_i=1$. We observed 1 success out of the 10 with $X_i=0$ and 2 successes out of the ten with $X_i=1$. MLE exists and is equal to $\hat{p}_{int}=0.1$ and $\hat{p}_{X}=0.2$.

I wish to do a parametric bootstrap of the kombinant

$$l(\hat{p_{int}})-l(p_{int})$$

where $l$ is the profiled likelihood function.

Here comes the problem: When you simulate new observations $Y^{sim}_1,...,Y^{sim}_{20}$ there is a large probability that the MLE does not exist. (e.g. if $Y_1,...,Y_{10}=0$ , which happens with approx. 0.35 probability).

What is the correct way to handle this problem? My intuition tells me its wrong to delete 40% of the simulated observations systematically. The goal is of course to use the estimated kombinant to produce a confidence-interval afterwards.

Comment: Could you clarify your notation? $\hat{p}_{int}$ is just the probabiity estimate based on the ten first observations? If all those are zeros, the estimated probability is zero ... so the mle does exist!